# How can I fix this issue when starting a Unity project?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Recently I updated Unity from version 2020.1.0b6 to 2020.1.16f1, but after starting the project, I started getting errors, and all two versions, I tried to reinstall, nothing helps. Below are links to screenshots
[photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUFcf.png)
[photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtpso.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please open **Package Manager** from **Window/Package Manager** on the menu.
There, you will be able to find packages that are related to the issues.
And please try to remove or update the packages.
If it's possible, would you share a screenshot of your **Package Manager**?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I switched to Package Manager and updated some packages to Verified and the errors were gone.